# How to get a list of newly installed packages after time x without removed packages after time x?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

From `/var/log/apt/history.log` it is possible to retrieve a list of installed and removed packages within time `x` based on timestamps, but editing the file is rather annoying, so I'm looking for a (set of) command(s) to get the effective list of packages which have been installed after timestamp `x_0`(= packages which have been installed after timestamp `x_0` minus packages which have been removed after timestamp `x_0`) in form of a list of package names.

`software-center` only displays changes chronologically and `synaptic` doesn't have a column which represents installation time. `dpkg-query` looks promising, but I'd appreciate some help from someone who can figure this out in minutes rather than days (the latter applies to myself).

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Did you ever get around to doing this? (Interested in the solution or contributing to it...)  But also too lazy to fully implement it all on my own...

Comment: @Fabby two answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `dpkg` doesn't show explicitly any information about installation dates of packages.

So, for a single run I would use something like the following one-liner:

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log |perl -lne 'next unless /^Start-Date: ([^ ]+)/ && $1 ge "2015-04-26" .. 1; next unless /^(Install|Purge|Remove): (.*)$/; $c = $1; $s = $2; $s =~ s/\([^\)]*\)//g; @packages = map { /^(.*?):/ ? $1 : $_} split /\s*,\s*/, $s; if ($c=~/^Install$/){ $h{$_} = 1 for @packages;} if ($c=~/^(Purge|Remove)$/) {delete $h{$_} for @packages;} END{print for sort keys %h;}'
```

Start date (x_0) has been hard-coded in the command (`"2015-04-26"`).

For time to time usage more suitable would be a stand-alone script, like this `installed_packages.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# use as follows:
# ./installed_packages.pl '2015-04-26' /var/log/apt/history.log
# or
# ./installed_packages.pl '2015-04-26 16:08:36' /var/log/apt/history.log

use strict;
use warnings;

# the script expects start date as first argument
my $START_DATE = shift @ARGV;

# hash (dict) to accumulate installed & not removed packages 
my %installed;
# flag to mark the beginning of "interesting" period of time
my $start = 0;

# loop over lines from the input file
while (my $line = <>){
    # remove end-of-line character 
    chomp $line;

    # skip everything until date becomes greater (or equal) than our x_0
    $start ||= $line =~ /^Start-Date: ([^ ]+)/ && $1 ge $START_DATE;
    next unless $start;

    # we're only interested in lines like 
    # Install: tupi-data:amd64 (0.2+git02-3build1, automatic), tupi:amd64 (0.2+git02-3build1), libquazip0:amd64 (0.6.2-0ubuntu1, automatic)
    # or
    # Remove: aptitude-common:amd64 (0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4)
    # + separate action (install/remove/purge) from package list
    next unless $line =~ /^(Install|Purge|Remove): (.*)$/; 
    my ($action, $packages_str) = ($1, $2);

    # remove versions from the list (they're in parentheses)
    $packages_str =~ s/\(.*?\)//g;

    # split single line into array of package names
    my @packages = split /\s*,\s*/, $packages_str;
    # remove architecture name (comes after ':')
    s/:.*// for @packages;

    # if packages have been installed, add them all to the hash (dict) of installed packages
    if ($action =~ /^Install$/ ){
        $installed{$_} = 1 for @packages;
    }

    # if packages have been removed, remove them all from the hash (dict) of installed packages
    if ($action =~ /^(Purge|Remove)$/) {
        delete $installed{$_} for @packages;
    }
}

# print all installed and not removed packages, in alphabetical order
for my $p ( sort keys %installed ){
    print "$p\n";
}
```

Usage:

```
./installed_packages.pl '2015-04-26' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

or

```
perl ./installed_packages.pl '2015-04-26' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

For frequent interactive use I'd add validation of script arguments (format of start date), implement `-h` switch to display short help, and possibly convert start date to named switch (`--start`).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I took the source code of [this response](https://askubuntu.com/a/615732/367165) and slightly expanded.

The added value is that you also get purged and removed packages and the output can be filtered with `grep`.

List installed packages:

```
./installed_packages.pl '2015-04-28' /var/log/apt/history.log | grep Installed:
```

or this for purged or removed:

```
./installed_packages.pl '2015-04-28' /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -Ei '(Purged|Removed)'
```

Source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# use as follows:
# ./installed_packages.pl '2015-04-26' /var/log/apt/history.log
# or
# ./installed_packages.pl '2015-04-26 16:08:36' /var/log/apt/history.log

use strict;
use warnings;

# the script expects start date as first argument
my $START_DATE = shift @ARGV;

# hash (dict) to accumulate installed & not removed packages 
my %installed;
my %removed;
my %purged;
# flag to mark the beginning of "interesting" period of time
my $start = 0;

# loop over lines from the input file
while (my $line = <>){
    # remove end-of-line character 
    chomp $line;

    # skip everything until date becomes greater (or equal) than our x_0
    $start ||= $line =~ /^Start-Date: ([^ ]+)/ && $1 ge $START_DATE;
    next unless $start;

    # we're only interested in lines like 
    # Install: tupi-data:amd64 (0.2+git02-3build1, automatic), tupi:amd64 (0.2+git02-3build1), libquazip0:amd64 (0.6.2-0ubuntu1, automatic)
    # or
    # Remove: aptitude-common:amd64 (0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4)
    # + separate action (install/remove/purge) from package list
    next unless $line =~ /^(Install|Purge|Remove): (.*)$/; 
    my ($action, $packages_str) = ($1, $2);

    # remove versions from the list (they're in parentheses)
    # $packages_str =~ s/\(.*?\)//g;

    # split single line into array of package names
    my @packages = split /\s*,\s*/, $packages_str;
    # remove architecture name (comes after ':')
    s/:.*// for @packages;

    # if packages have been installed, add them all to the hash (dict) of installed packages
    if ($action =~ /^Install$/ ){
        $installed{$_} = 1 for @packages;
    }

    # if packages have been removed, add them all to the hash (dict) of installed packages
    if ($action =~ /^Remove$/) {
        $removed{$_} = 1 for @packages;
    }

    # if packages have been purged, add them all to the hash (dict) of installed packages
    if ($action =~ /^Purge$/) {
        $purged{$_} = 1 for @packages;
    }
}

# print all installed and not removed packages, in alphabetical order
for my $p ( sort keys %installed ){
    print "Installed: $p\n";
}

for my $p ( sort keys %removed ){
    print "Removed: $p\n";
}

for my $p ( sort keys %removed ){
    print "Purged: $p\n";
}
```

Comment: Good one! Upvoted!