# How to view all the packages installed in Ubuntu in the order of installation

Tags: dpkg, timestamp

I want to know which packages were installed since a particular date. I see that  'dpkg-l' command does not give  the installation timestamp. Is there any option in Ubuntu to view the package installation timestamps of all the installed  packages ?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/566964/how-to-get-a-list-of-newly-installed-packages-after-time-x-without-removed-packa/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the list the installed packages sorted by install date/time using the following command:

```
grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log
```

Comment: OP wants to know *any option in Ubuntu to view the package installation timestamps of all the installed packages*